# sp_xml_preparedocument and use of the Namespace. I get an error "XML parsing error: Reference to undeclared namespace prefix: 'a'." in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, xml, namespaces

Please help. After reading all google and stackoverflow :) my brain does not work anymore.

I have below TSQL (running on SQL Server 2012)

I cannot figure out where I need to declare my a: namespace? And how many namespaces I need to declare?

```
DECLARE @XML AS XML
DECLARE @hDoc AS INT

SELECT @XML = '<GetAssetWarrantyResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
  <GetAssetWarrantyResult xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Dell.AWR.Domain.Asset" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <a:Faults />
    <a:Response>
      <a:DellAsset>
        <a:AssetParts i:nil="true" />
        <a:CountryLookupCode>5252</a:CountryLookupCode>
        <a:CustomerNumber>645651</a:CustomerNumber>
      </a:DellAsset>
    </a:Response>
  </GetAssetWarrantyResult>
</GetAssetWarrantyResponse>'

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @hDoc OUTPUT, @XML

SELECT CountryLookupCode
FROM OPENXML(@hDoc, 'GetAssetWarrantyResponse/GetAssetWarrantyResult/a:Response/a:DellAsset')
WITH 
(
CountryLookupCode   [nvarchar](20)  'a:CountryLookupCode'
)

EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @hDoc
GO
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to specify the namespace prefixes when invoking `sp_xml_preparedocument`. In this case you have the `a` namespace and the default namespace (the one without prefix: `xmlns="...."`) :

```
EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument 
        @hDoc OUTPUT
        , @XML
        , '<root xmlns:d="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Dell.AWR.Domain.Asset"/>'
```

And use the registered prefixes properly :

```
SELECT CountryLookupCode
FROM OPENXML(@hDoc, 'd:GetAssetWarrantyResponse/d:GetAssetWarrantyResult/a:Response/a:DellAsset')
WITH 
(
    CountryLookupCode   [nvarchar](20)  'a:CountryLookupCode'
)
```

Comment: Hi har07, super things:) works. I have tried exactly what you had here but i was missing "<root" I was thinking I had to put "<GetAssetWarrantyResponse"  :). THANK YOU THANK YOU

Comment: @user188145 you're welcome. Also look into marc_s' answer for the newer approach, if possible :)

Comment: yes defiantly. I have one question I hope you can have a quick answer:) now that my query worked I have imported my XML files to a TABLE to a COLUMN_XML with data type XML when I run the select it queries only one raw from that table. any ideas? should I open another Question? :)

Comment: hmm.. I think you should open another question. Can't have a clear picture of your new problem solely based on your above comment...

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the **built-in, native XQuery** support in SQL Server:

```
DECLARE @XML AS XML

SELECT @XML = '<GetAssetWarrantyResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
  <GetAssetWarrantyResult xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Dell.AWR.Domain.Asset" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <a:Faults />
    <a:Response>
      <a:DellAsset>
        <a:AssetParts i:nil="true" />
        <a:CountryLookupCode>5252</a:CountryLookupCode>
        <a:CustomerNumber>645651</a:CustomerNumber>
      </a:DellAsset>
    </a:Response>
  </GetAssetWarrantyResult>
</GetAssetWarrantyResponse>'

;WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://tempuri.org/', 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Dell.AWR.Domain.Asset' AS ns)
SELECT
    @XML.value('(GetAssetWarrantyResponse/GetAssetWarrantyResult/ns:Response/ns:DellAsset/ns:CountryLookupCode)[1]', 'int')
```

In terms of XML namespaces: you need to define **all those used** in your XML document up to the point where you want to get the data from